# Auto complete not working on Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We have bootstrap modal in our website and we are trying to implement autocomplete

its not working only on the Modal.

Here is the code

```
$( "#emp_id" ).autocomplete({
              source: "/search/autocomplete?employeeName=1",
              minLength: 1,
              select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#emp_id').val(ui.item.value);
              }
            });

<input type="text" name="leadid" id="emp_id"  value=""/>
```

I tried following css

```
ul .ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 1500 !important;
}
```

didn't worked out

Comment: what about using this plugin https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
$( "#emp_id" ).autocomplete({
          source: "/search/autocomplete?employeeName=1"

        });
```

Also make sure you are using necessary plugins. Reference : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling autocomplete function on page load, it won't work in modal because your autocomplete textbox will be hidden.

Try Calling the autocomplete function once modal is displayed. It should work.

jsfiddle link would help to debug your exact issue.